# Get Object from object array based on value of certain key with rapidjson

Tags: c++, json, rapidjson

I have [this JSON file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andruzzzhka/BeatSaberScrappedData/master/beatSaverScrappedData.json) I'm making a web request to.

It's an array of JSON objects as you can see and I want to get the object that has a matching hash to. What I have my end goal is to get the `upVotes` and `downVotes` from `stats`.

Here is an individual object [example](https://beatsaver.com/api/maps/by-hash/ad6c9f88d63259a95e39397c31be2981c4beb744).

Also, I'm trying not to use any for loops if possible since I want as much performance as I can.

Basically, say, in my code, I have a hash

```
4b2da842b687ec4cfbc948c583c21c79d4120de0
```

and, I want the object that has that value for the hash in the JSON.

Comment: It's hard to give feedback without a [mcve].

Comment: @TedLyngmo i dont really have any example code its not really a issue just a question

Comment: Have you tried using `jq`?

Comment: @MartinYork i have not where would i start? is there a example for what im doing

Comment: On the command line: `curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andruzzzhka/BeatSaberScrappedData/master/beatSaverScrappedData.json | jq '. | map(select(.hash == "4b2da842b687ec4cfbc948c583c21c79d4120de0"))'`

Comment: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/

Comment: @Futuremappermydud Does jq actually solve your problem or are you still trying to use c++ to parse the JSON?

Comment: @MartinYork im required to use c++ yes

Comment: @Futuremappermydud Does this help? https://gist.github.com/Loki-Astari/ee4a2a83de877378bfbca5d3513e31d8

Comment: @Futuremappermydud: Which loop are you trying to avoid? The loop on array? How are you querying this JSON? Fetch once and query all the up and down votes after?